# Is there a way with Spring Security to cache token introspection result?

Tags: keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring boot REST API protected by Keycloak with Spring Security.

I can't find if there is a way to prevent token introspection on every request (i.e. caching introspection result for a short period). Everytime I hit the API, token is checked upon Keycloak and this is not great for performance :(

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: First, is introspection necessary? JWT is a common optimization for something like this.

Comment: I think this is the endpoint used to check token validity ?

Comment: Yes, this is an option. Though if you are checking with the authorization server for validity, I'd imagine you'd want to check on every request, in case an administrator has invalidated the token (e.g. it didn't just timeout). If you don't need this level of revocation, then JWT can remove the need to check with the authorization server for validity since a JWT's validity is self-contained.

Comment: any solution that got implemented / worked? - @RomainWilbert

Answer (score 7):

This is sort of the tradeoff that you make when you use opaque tokens (which require introspection).

With opaque tokens:

- OAuth 2.0 Clients can't see the contents
- Authorization Servers can revoke the token at any time

The tradeoff is that you need to check with the Authorization Server on every request to make sure the token hasn't been invalidated.

With JWT:

- OAuth 2.0 Clients may inspect the contents of the token
- The JWT carries its own expiry information

What you get in exchange for the performance benefit of JWT is that it can't be invalidated, only expired.

So, this wasn't your question precisely, but you asked about performance, and JWT is a very common way to address the performance hit of opaque tokens.

You might also ask yourself if you need the additional security benefits of opaque tokens for every path in your application. Could you use JWT for some paths and check with the authorization server for higher-security paths?

Anyway, you asked about caching. Yes, Spring Boot publishes an instance of `OpaqueTokenIntrospector` for you, which you can override with one that caches:

```java
@Component
public class CachingOpaqueTokenIntrospector
        implements OpaqueTokenIntrospector {

    private final NimbusOpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector = 
        // ... construct

    @Override
    public OAuth2AuthenticatedPrincipal introspect(String token) {
        // call delegate introspector and cache        
    }
}
```

You could use the `@Cacheable` annotation on the `introspect` method, for example.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But this adds cache to the server side of Spring oauth2 server...I  use Keycloak and I would like cache on the client side (where the call to introspection endpoint is called).

Comment: What do you mean "on the client side"? The example above is what to do in a Java application that is acting as a resource server (a REST API). Are you asking for what to do in the browser?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. This answer is very good but the hint at the end should be taken with caution: I would not recommend `@Cachable` on the `#introspect()` Method because then you cache all items with the same expiry. The introspection endpoint will return tokens with different expiry times and you could introduce a security gap by allowing stale access tokens.